# TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' with any

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am having difficulty understanding why the compiler excludes `null` from the set of types possible for `arg` (or alternatively I do not understand the diagnostic message).

```
    static vetStringNullable(arg:any): string|null {
        if (typeof arg === 'string') {
            return arg;
        }
        if (typeof arg === 'null') {
            return arg;
        }
        throw TypeError('Vetted value is not of type string or null.');
    }
```

The above code yields the following compiler diagnostic:

```
TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"null"' have no overlap.
```

Edit: In light of the accepted answer, I have changed the function as follows:

```
    static vetStringNullable(arg:any): string|null {
        if (typeof arg === 'string' || arg === null) {
            return arg;
        }
        throw TypeError('Vetted value is not of type string or null.');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message you're getting is simply stating that `null` is not in the list of defined types. The reason for this is that there's no such thing as a `null` type in JavaScript/TypeScript.

```
console.log(typeof null); // "object"
```

On the other hand, there is an `undefined` type:

```
let a;
console.log(typeof a); // "undefined"
```